# django python: how to filter depending on the slug of pk of one app as foreign key in another app

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create an eCommerce site to learn python and django. I have created an app called category. This has 2 tables called Category and Subcategory. Category table's pk is a foreign key in Subcategory table. In category app's views.py, i have override the get_queryset in SubcategoryListView to show the subcategory items specific to the category on which the user clicks. So far everything is working fine.
If from the home page, i click on Kids link, my url shows http://localhost:8000/category/kids/

I created another app called product(Which i am not sure if this is the correct way or should i use the category app for products too). This has a table called Product. Both Category table's pk and Subcategory table's pk are foreign keys in Product table. When i click on the subcategory link, i expect to show all the products that belong to that subcategory. I am not able to achieve this.
Like in the kids page if i click on link Dresses, i want the url to be 
http://localhost:8000/category/kids/dresses-kids 
(dresses-kids is the slug for Dresses in kids subcategory)

my product/views.py is as follows:

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    template_name = "product_list.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(subcategory__slug__contains=self.kwargs['slug'])
```

Is the above code correct? Something similar had worked for filter on category in subcategory

I am not sure what should be there in my urls.py. Also which urls.py to use, category apps urls.py or product apps urls.py.

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

Edit1:

I tried something like this in category/urls.py

```
path('kids/<slug:slug>/', ProductListView.as_view()),
```

When i manually enter the url as 
    http://localhost:8000/category/kids/dresses-kids/
i go to the next page where i see the list of products under dresses but from the subcategory page (http://localhost:8000/category/kids/), when i click on dresses, the url does not change and i will still be there in the subcategory page.

Also you may notice that i have hardcoded kids in the urls.py. I don't know how to get that dynamically. Requesting help in this regard too.

Thanks in advance.

Edit2:

@User42 thank you for your response. The category/urls.py is as follows:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path

from product.views import ProductListView
from .views import SubcategoryListView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', SubcategoryListView.as_view()),
    path('kids/<slug:slug>/', ProductListView.as_view()),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Template file for ProductListView is as follows:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="album py-5 bg-light">
          <div class="container">
              <div class="row">

                  {% for object in object_list %}

                  <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}">
                  <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ object.image }}" height="400" width="100"/>
                  </a>
                    <a class="card-body"></a>
                    <a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}"><p class="card-text text-center">{{ object.name }}</p></a>
                </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

{% endblock %}
```

The product/views.py is as follows:

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView, UpdateView, ListView, DetailView

from category.models import Subcategory
from product.forms import ProductForm
from product.models import Product

class ProductListView(ListView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    template_name = "product/product_list.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(subcategory__slug__contains=self.kwargs['slug'])

class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    template_name = "product/product_detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        print(context)
        return context
```

Please let me know if you need any other details.

Thanks in advance.

Edit3:

@SachinKukreja thank you for your response.

The template for subcategory is as follows:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <br />
    <br />
     <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
          <div class="container">
              <div class="row">

                  {% for object in object_list %}

                  <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}">
                  <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ object.image.url }}" height="400" width="100"/>
                  </a>
                    <a class="card-body"></a>
                    <a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}"><p class="card-text text-center">{{ object.name }}</p></a>
                </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: What happens when you click on the subcategory link? What error do you see?

Comment: @WillKeeling  I stays in the subcategory page itself. No errors shown

Comment: Share your urls.py, template file and view file via paste service

Comment: The catetgory/urls.py is as follows:

`urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', SubcategoryListView.as_view()),
    path('kids/<slug:slug>/', ProductListView.as_view()),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Comment: @User42 since the code is not properly displayed in the comment, and since there is number of character restriction, i will put it in the edit section of the question.

Comment: @Namrata always share your code in the edit section of the question, irrespective of the character limit in the comments.

Comment: Please add the template for subcategory page as well.

Comment: Hi, can some one please guide me?